# How to make Photo Picker show images from Google Photos?

Tags: android, photo-picker, android-photo-picker

Is there any way to make [Photo Picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) show images from Google Photos?

I've tested it on an emulator API 33 and it only shows images from the Gallery (even though there are images in Google Photos and Google Drive).

When I tested it on a physical device (API < 30), it shows images from the Gallery and from the Google Drive, but not from the Google Photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now available through Photo Picker:

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/02/cloud-photos-now-available-in-android-photo-picker.html